# React — have active item state stay with menu component when loaded into new page

Tags: reactjs

I have a menu component that is losing it's state when loaded into different pages. I'm a React noobie and trying to figure out the best way to manage "active" menu classes. I am using react-router and I think I'm making this more difficult than it needs to be

The Nav is included in different pages like this:

```
// some component
<header className="autohide header-down">
  <Nav />
</header>

// some other component
<footer className="autohide header-down">
  <Nav />
</footer>
```

I'm using this inside the  component to set the 'active' menu item, but (and I should have expected this) when the the Nav component gets loaded into a new page it loses the active state:

```
getInitialState(){
  return {
    selected:''
  }
},
setFilter(filter) {
  this.setState({selected  : filter})
  this.props.onChangeFilter(filter);
},
isActive(value){
  return 'nav-link '+((value===this.state.selected) ?'active':'');
},
onClick(){

},
render()...
```

And this on each link:

```
<Link className={this.isActive('settings')} onClick={this.setFilter.bind(this, 'settings')} to="/settings">SETTINGS</Link>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: you need to store the state outside of the component and pass it in. What are you using as a router?

Comment: @Blairanderson I'm using react-router (which I think has built in active functionality, but I don't know how to use it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your current setup, just pass in an `active` prop to your header from each component:

```
const Dashboard = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <div>
      <Nav active="dashboard" />
    </div>
  }
})

const About = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <div>
      <Nav active="about" />
    </div>

  }
})

const Messages = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <div>
      <Nav active="messages" />
      // other stuff
    </div>
  }
})

const Nav = React.createClass({
  isActive(value){
    return 'nav-link '+((value===this.props.active) ?'active':'');
  },
  render() {
    return <div>
      <Link className={this.isActive("settings")}>Settings</Link>
      <Link className={this.isActive("dashboard")}>Dashboard</Link>
    </div>
  }
})



render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Dashboard} />
      <Route path="about" component={About} />
      <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox}>
        <Route path="messages/:id" component={Messages} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.body)
```

Comment: in the Nav var, I don't see how the className is set for the active item. i.e., <Link className="?" active="{this.isActive("settings")}>...

Comment: I got it working... just changed active={"this.isActive"...} to className={this.isActive...}